# Coding in R to break long, lat, altitude and timezone

Tags: r

I am looking to break a field with multiple coordinates to extract only the required coordinates. In the example below, the first field is PK and coordinates are long, lat, altitude and UTZ Time. It's a single string with collection of points.

```
PK          Coordinates
34FDSMT    LINESTRING ZM(85.0, 32.4, 1200, 1642028770800; 87.2, 35.7, 1000, 1642028870800)
```

I want the output to include

```
PK           Coordinates
34FDSMT      LINESTRING ZM(85.0, 32.4, 1642028770800; 87.2, 35.7, 1642028870800)
```

Comment: Do you just want to remove altitude, assuming it is the third position? It appears the only difference between the desired output is the removal of 1200 and 1000. Is this correct?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Yea that’s true. I only want to remove the third position. Just to add a little more layer into it - the coordinates field has over 30 points in it and I want to remove the 3rd position from all the points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be more elegant ways to do this, but using the `tidyr::unnest` and functions in the `dplyr` packages, you can achieve this the following way:

Data (note: I made a second observation that has 3 coordinates to see if it successfully removes the third position for for an unknown number of coordinates)

```
df <- data.frame(PK = c("34FDSMT", "39TEST"),
                 Coordinates = c("LINESTRING ZM(85.0, 32.4, 1200, 1642028770800; 87.2, 35.7, 1000, 1642028870800)",
                                 "LINESTRING TEST(55.5, 12.4, 1100, 1519821970800; 17.2, 45.3, 9000, 4581564848700; 19.2, 23.3, 7000, 1789451878700)"))
```

Code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% group_by(PK) %>%
  mutate(Coordinates = strsplit(Coordinates, ",")) %>% # splits everything by a comma
  unnest(Coordinates) %>% # converts to long form
  filter(row_number() %% 3 != 0) %>% # removes observations in the undesired positions
  mutate(Coordinates = paste(Coordinates, collapse = ",")) %>% # returns to single column
  distinct() # removes duplicates created in the process
```

Output:

```
# PK      Coordinates                                                                                     
# 1 34FDSMT LINESTRING ZM(85.0, 32.4, 1642028770800; 87.2, 35.7, 1642028870800)                             
# 2 39TEST  LINESTRING TEST(55.5, 12.4, 1519821970800; 17.2, 45.3, 4581564848700; 19.2, 23.3, 1789451878700)
```

Note this only works if you are consistently removing the third position, commas are separating the data within a position, and semicolons (or some other non-comma symbols) are are separating the different readings.